# How we declare ordinal no for multiple file selection

Tags: java

Currently when i select a single file the I use

```
int ordinal = 0;
String sessionToken = IIMessionUtil.getSessionToken(request, response);
String objectID = IWMSessionUtil.getObjectId(request, response);
System.out.println("session"+sessionToken+"objectID"+objectID);
ordinal = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ordinal"));
System.out.println("ordinal "+ordinal);
String  imageString = helper.getPageAttachment(sessionToken,objectID, ordinal);
```

Please tell me how can I give value for `ordinal` When selecting Multiple file and pass it.

Comment: Where is `IWMSessionUtil` coming from ? Without more context, I'm afraid your question is impossible to understand.

Comment: Where do you select something? Explain your code and what it does. And what are `request, response, IWMSessionUtil` and `helper`?